# Visual studio locals window in debugger mentions two different types for certain variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In the visual studio 2022 debugger, the "Types" column shows the type of each variable in the current namespace.

[image]

Some values, however, consist of two types as indicated by the curly braces below:

[image]

Why do some variables appear to have two types, one in curly braces and one not? What is the difference between the two mentioned types.

Comment: The type inside the braces is the actual type of the variable, while the type outside the braces is the declared type of the variable. The actual type is the type the variable has at runtime, while the declared type is the type explicitly declared in the code. When a variable's actual type differs from its declared type, the debugger will show both types in the Type column. But I can't find documentation about it, maybe you can submit a pull request.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT where would I submit such a pull request?

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues  You can find the github jump link below the relevant documents, and you can enter this page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First type is the static type of the member. The one in the parenthesis is the runtime type of the actual object.